# I have a PHP foreach loop that is displaying not as I am intending due to the letter casing of some of the array keys

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach loop that is iterating through an associative array, but creating an extra iteration because of the casing of one of the array keys.

The array looks like the below

```
$this->daily_conversion_data['cnb_utm_totals'] = ["sourceone" => 56, 
"SourceTwo" => 76, 
"SourceThree" => 55, 
"SourceOne" => 6];
```

The foreach loop is below:

```
foreach($this->daily_conversion_data['cnb_utm_totals'] as $utm_source => $utm_data)
            {
}
```

I need "sourceone" and "SourceOne" to be combined into one array key. So instead of "sourceone" having a total of 56 "SourceOne" having a total of 6, it would be "SourceOne" having a total of 62. Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This seems like something that would be better solved when creating the array in the first place. Convert the key to a common case to combine them.

Comment: @Barmar Agreed. I was hoping there was a way to do it simply with a stringtolower() somehow

Comment: Loop through the array, call `strtolower()` on the key, and create a new array that combines the elements with the same lowercase keys.